# Weird runtime behavior of `scipy.linalg.solve_triangular` and `trtrs`

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, linear-solver, lapack, blas

I want to understand the time complexity of [`scipy.linalg.solve_triangular`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_triangular.html), which calls [`trtrs`](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d4/dc1/group__trtrs.html) from LAPACK under the hood, so I wrote the following benchmarking script:

```py
from time import perf_counter

import numpy as np
import scipy


def benchmark(p):
    L = np.ones((p, p))
    b = np.zeros((p))

    start_time = perf_counter()
    for _ in range(10):
        scipy.linalg.solve_triangular(L, b,
                                      lower=True,
                                      unit_diagonal=True,
                                      overwrite_b=True,
                                      check_finite=False)
    end_time = perf_counter()

    return end_time - start_time


if __name__ == "__main__":
    elapsed = benchmark(1<<8)
    print(elapsed)
    elapsed = benchmark(1<<10)
    print(elapsed)
    elapsed = benchmark(1<<12)
    print(elapsed)
    elapsed = benchmark(1<<14)
    print(elapsed)
    elapsed = benchmark(1<<16)
    print(elapsed)
```

The output is

```
0.12597245816141367
0.03438423713669181
0.05818071821704507
0.1374253649264574
1.6546398717910051
```

This is surprising: why does solving a larger problem take less time, as in `1<<10` and `1<<12` vs `1<<8`?

The more important question is: what's the time complexity of `scipy.linalg.solve_triangular` for $L \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{p}$? I would expect it to be $O(p^2)$ with [forward](https://algowiki-project.org/en/Forward_substitution)/[backward](https://algowiki-project.org/en/Backward_substitution) substitution, but [rumors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61920245/computational-complexity-of-backsolve-in-r) are that triangular solve may take $O(p^3)$ in some implementations.

Comment: It's probably just some spurious startup / compilation time for the first call. What happens if you start from `1<<6` instead? Or swap the order of the calls?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Thanks for the pointer! I think I have figured it out. See my answer below!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Federico Poloni's comment, I have revised the script as below. It looks like `scipy.linalg.solve_triangular` has time complexity $O(p^2)$, because the execution time quadruples as the problem size doubles.

```
from time import perf_counter

import numpy as np
import scipy


def benchmark(p):
    L = np.ones((p, p))
    b = np.zeros((p))

    # Warm up
    scipy.linalg.solve_triangular(L, b,
                                  lower=True,
                                  unit_diagonal=True,
                                  overwrite_b=True,
                                  check_finite=False)

    start_time = perf_counter()
    for _ in range(64):
        scipy.linalg.solve_triangular(L, b,
                                      lower=True,
                                      unit_diagonal=True,
                                      overwrite_b=True,
                                      check_finite=False)
    end_time = perf_counter()

    return end_time - start_time


if __name__ == "__main__":
    last_elapsed = None
    for i in range(16):
        elapsed = benchmark(1<<i)
        if last_elapsed is not None:
            print(i, elapsed, elapsed/last_elapsed)
        else:
            print(i, elapsed)
        last_elapsed = elapsed
```